# Delphi - Simulate (multi)touch input

Tags: delphi, touch, multi-touch

Is there an actual way of simulating the touch input inside of delphi app, and if so, is it possible to simulate multi touch as well?

The problem example: certain app accepts only touch input for some actions.

The desired solution example: Use keyboard keys to simulate the touch inputs. It could be vital/very desired, to be able to use Key "A" to simulate touch on coordinates (x, y), Key "B" on (x+n, y+m), and to be able to press either one by one or both keys simultaneously. (The physical limit of 3 keys here should be ignored).

Comment: I don't know what platform you are asking about. If we knew that then we might have more chance to help.

Comment: Deleted.

@DavidHeffernan by platform you mean version of Delphi?

Comment: No. Although that would help too. We don't know what systems your program runs on. Or what frameworks your program uses.

Comment: I wasn't talking for specific application, but looking for rather general solution here...

Comment: So you want a general solution that works for all operating systems and all frameworks?

Comment: Well, for start, I'm asking for at least one example. Since it's delphi app, I thought that it would be considered as an Windows OS usage, and the frameworks - Well yes. If I want to simulate multitouch inputs on a machine, I want it working on any app, no matter which framework it uses. Does that not make sense? :/

Comment: Delphi now can target windows, osx, iOS and Android. It has both VCL on Windows and FMX on all other platforms. The question still doesn't give any of the information that I asked for in this regard. Perhaps all you need is to send WM_GESTURE messages. Hard to know.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about multi touch but you can simulate a mouse click (single touch). Will not work on things like TWebBrowser, TMapView, and maybe TListView. Theoretically you could modify the source code of where Firemonkey gets it's multi touch data from the hardware and send in your own data at that point but that is beyond the scope of this answer.

```
function TForm1.FindControlAtPoint(aParent: TControl; aPos: TPointF): TControl;
var
  I: Integer;
  Control, ChildControl: TControl;
  S: String;
begin
  Result := nil;

  // Check all the child controls and find the one at the coordinates
  for I := aParent.Controls.Count – 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    Control := aParent.Controls[I];
    S := Control.ClassName;
    if Control.PointInObject(aPos.X, aPos.Y) then
    begin
      ChildControl := FindControlAtPoint(Control, aPos);
      if Assigned(ChildControl) and ChildControl.HitTest then
        Exit(ChildControl)
      else if Control.HitTest then
        Exit(Control);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

There is a demo project available [here](http://www.fmxexpress.com/remotely-control-apps-via-app-tethering-or-rest-in-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/).

Comment: Thank you for suggested answer. Vote up, however, I will wait if someone has better answer regarding multitouch specifically for accepting...